# Angular Cannot find module in new folder

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this problem on stackBlitz with an Angular Project. I created a folder models with an interface "book.ts". I'm trying to import this in the book.component that's in the folder components. You can see the folders' structure in the pictures. If I put my interface file in other "models" siblings folders, like
"feature" or "shared", I have no problem; the system found it. 
If I put this file in my desired folder this create this issue, this can't find the module. I can't found a solution to solve it. Help me please.

I[[image: Interface[1]]

[image: Component]

Comment: Can you share the link? Also, I find that the UI is sometimes slow to catch up. Unless you see an actual runtime error, then there's no problem.

Comment: @Andy, sometimes stackblitz mark as "not found' but it's not true. Generally if you save, and reload, this red underline disapear

Answer (score 0):

I used this command for generating your model and I imported it without any problem.

```
ng generate interface models/book --type=model
```

Can you try it.